# How to colour categorise population estimates using GRID3 Settlement Extents in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, extents, heat-map, population

I am new to ArcGIS Pro and geospatial data in general. I have downloaded settlement extents data from https://grid3.org/. I had naively thought the data would display the population in a heatmap like manner, such as from green(lowest population) to red(highest population). But this is what I have
[image: Gray Settlement Extent]

This is how the attribute table looks like [image: Attribute Table]

My two questions are:

1. What would the process in ArcGIS Pro to create a population heatmap?
2. How to avoid the settlement extents covering the countries boundaries ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Placing a bullet list of questions in your Question  will generate closure votes. Please Edit your Question to ask one question (preferably the one that has been answered).

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no heat-map is because with a GIS Software (like ArcGIS Pro) it leaves it up to you to decide on *exactly **how** you want to the data to **look***.

1. To show the country layer *above* your settlement data, drag the layer on the contents pane so it appears right at the top.
2. To display the data as a heat-map you need to change the *symbology* and pick the attribute (maybe population, maybe pop_un_adj -it's up to you) you want displayed in different colours.

I suggest that you play around with the layer order (contents pane) and symbology and search the online documentation (or just the internet in general) for more information on exactly what you want to do. Also search using "*ArcGIS Pro*" rather than *Arc* or *ArcGIS* as the older version of the software ArcGIS Desktop is still widely used.

The latest documentation for heat-maps is here:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/heat-map.htm